# Page citation in soul

Tags: biblatex, soul

I'm using the `soul` package.

This works:

```
\ul{lorem ipsum}
```

This doesn't work:

```
\ul{lorem \cite{foo} ipsum}
```

This does work:

```
\ul{lorem {\cite{foo}} ipsum}
```

Neither of these works:

```
\ul{lorem  \cite[42]{foo}  ipsum}
\ul{lorem {\cite[42]{foo}} ipsum}
```

because `soul` says, "I came across hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces, which I can't handle."

`soul` suggests to put it in an `\mbox` or `\hbox`; neither of these worked for me.

I've read [Hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49466/37357) but I'm not sure how relevant it is. (I tried its suggestions and couldn't get anything working.)

How *can* I place such a citation in `soul`? Ideally, the citation should be hyphenatable.

**M(N)WE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.
\end{thebibliography}

The \ul{underlined text on \cite[42]{lamport94} is underlined}, presumably.

\end{document}
```

---

The proposed solution (replacing `soul` with `ulem`) doesn't seem to work on an actual BibTeX entry:

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{uncivil,
  author = {Ismael, Jacqueline S. and Shereen T. Ismael},
  title = {The Arab Spring and the uncivil state},
  journal = {Arab Studies Quarterly},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {35.3},
  pages = {229--240},
  owner = {wchargin},
  timestamp = {2014.02.12}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

The \uline{underlined text on \cite[42]{uncivil} is underlined}, presumably.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The first `pdflatex` and `bibtex` commands work fine, but running `pdflatex` again gives the error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.11 ... text on \cite[42]{uncivil} is underlined}
                                                  , presumably.
```

Comment: I made your second MWE self-contained using `filecontents`. BTW even more strange to me is, that the output looks still fine despite the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I had noticed that the output *looks* fine, but the PDF processing stops and all, so there must be something going on... I can't help but think that if it's generating errors, there'll be something else trouble down the road by ignoring them.

Comment: Don't use underlining. It's not used in good typography.

Comment: @egreg I know; it's a school assignment that mandates that you underline your thesis statement, even though it may look terrible and contradict any design standard. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both your examples work fine with if you put the unbreakable material inside `\mbox`.

1. **1st MWE**

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[american]{babel}
   \usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
   \usepackage{soul}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{thebibliography}{9}
   \bibitem{lamport94}
     Leslie Lamport,
     \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
     Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
     2nd Edition,
     1994.
   \end{thebibliography}

   The \ul{underlined text on \mbox{\cite[42]{lamport94}} is underlined}, presumably.

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. **2nd MWE**

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[american]{babel}
   \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

   \usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
   @ARTICLE{uncivil,
     author = {Ismael, Jacqueline S. and Shereen T. Ismael},
     title = {The Arab Spring and the uncivil state},
     journal = {Arab Studies Quarterly},
     year = {2013},
     volume = {35.3},
     pages = {229--240},
     owner = {wchargin},
     timestamp = {2014.02.12}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

   \begin{document}

   The \uline{underlined text on \mbox{\cite[42]{uncivil}} is underlined}, presumably.

   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: It doesn't work for `\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}` though. (Sorry, will update question.)

Comment: @WChargin For me, both the MWEs work with `\mbox`

Comment: Yep, working for me too now. Must have been some silly mistake on my part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\uline` from `ulem` As noted by Karl, you have to put the `\cite` inside a `\mbox` to make it work with second mwe also.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}  % biblatex likes it
\usepackage{biblatex}         % for \cite
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}             % for \uline


\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.
\end{thebibliography}

The \uline{underlined text on \mbox{\cite[42]{lamport94}} is underlined}, presumably.

\end{document}
```

This is just a work around though.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, strange... although this example works, it doesn't seem to work with an actual BibTeX entry. Please see my edit.

Comment: It works putting the citation in a `\mbox`

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks. Morning, I was in a hurry to edit.